# Angular2 no rewrite entirely the URI it's executed from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an angular2 app running on top of .NET project. We access the app at `http://example.com/index/app`.

But immediately after the angular2 app starts running and appearing, our URL is rewrited in the browser as: `http://example.com/#/dashboard` for example.

Trying to go directly to `http://example.com/index/app/#/dashboard` redirects or more precisely rewrite our url to `http://example.com/#/dashboard` an displays the app.

How can I prevent this behavior to constantly have the full URI? `http://example.com/index/app/#/dashboard` Angular2 part being only the after `#` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base path is wrong. You have to add

```
<base href="~/index/app" />
```

to your html (index.html, index.cshtml, or _Layout.cshtml, depending on the way you have done it) document. Remove the `~` if you are not using Razor views.

#### Update based on comments

You'll have to define a section within your `_Layout.cshtml` which will render it on a per view basis.

in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("base", required: false)
</head>
```

in your `Views/Index/App.cshtml`:

```
@section base {
    <base href="~/index/app"/>
}
```

Comment: Do I have to change the base only on the page which calls the Angular JS files or in the global layout? Because since I'v also routes like `/api/actions` or `/index/login` I want to be able to access it.

Comment: Depends on your setup. You should only have a single one. Also how is `/api/actions` related to it? It doesn't delivery any razor views, its just json/xml/data return. I dunno how your project is structured, there are multiple ways on how to setup Angular2 with ASP.NET Core (i.e. via some `/Home/Index` layout, by completely removing any Razor Controllers and doing it in the _Layout file or just by using static files and an index.html. If your angular2 application starts, it means you already had to add it once before, but you set it to `<base href="/"/>`. You just need to change this

Comment: Angular JS built files are included in a cshtml view attached to `/Index/App`. But in the project we also have non angular pages: `/Index/Login` (Login page/view is our entry point: the authentication logic is made in ASP.NET Core side, then a token is generated and the App Angular2 view is called). Also we have our local API with routes such as `/api/action`. Since Angular2 app was "called" by `/Index/App` view, I thought the `/Index/App` URI would appear.

Comment: Then add/change it in your /Index/App.cshtml, though you will then have to use sections to render it only for that single controller action (`<head>` must be defined in the header)

Comment: Thanks by adding proper sections it works perfectly.